# Why does the custom directive have "ng-dirty" class at starting?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want my custom directive like angular's directive to support `required` option, so I referenced `ngModel` in directive. but It don't like other directive that don't have `ng-dirty` class at starting till you input something.

What can I do?

[My JSFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/hellolibo/1aqc3rgn/1/)

**HTML code:**

```
<div ng-app="myDemo" ng-controller="myDemoCtrl">
    <div>{{name}}</div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
    <form>
        <input type="text" required ng-model="name">
        <list ng-model="items" required></list>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS code**

```
form .ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
form .demo-list.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
    border: none;
}
form .demo-list.ng-invalid.ng-dirty input {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**JS code:**

```
angular.module('myDemo', []).controller('myDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = '';
    $scope.items = undefined;
}).directive('list', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        require: '?ngModel',
        template: '<div class="demo-list"><input type="text" ng-model="addItems"></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            if (!ngModelCtrl) {
                return;
            }

            ngModelCtrl.$isEmpty = function(value) {
                return !(angular.isArray(value) && value.length > 0);
            };

            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
                return angular.isArray(modelValue) ? modelValue : [];
            });

            ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
                scope.addItems = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue.join(',');
            };

            scope.$watch('addItems', function() {
                var newList = scope.addItems.length == 0 ? [] : scope.addItems.split(',');
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(newList);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Update**

[it's working, JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/hellolibo/1aqc3rgn/3/)

Comment: Can you add a little bit about what is your expected output, and what is current output?

Comment: @KhalidHussain I expect it does not have 'ng-dirty' class at the beginning.

Comment: I added "if(newValue === oldValue) return;" into $watch callback function, It working fine now .